# Preview document not updated

Tags: pdf, preview, bug

I am currently using Macbook pro 2017 Touch Bar that is on the Mojave OS. I do most of my work on Preview. I have noticed recently that my preview does not load the latest document version. For example, I made my edits on my preview document on 30/1/2020. However, when I opened the very same document again the next day on 31/1/2020, it does not load the edits that i have made on 30/1/2020. Instead, it showed edits from a much earlier version. Therefore, every time before I can do my work, I had to manually check if the preview document is on the latest version. If it is not, I will need to revert manually. Is there any way I can correct this issue?

***This is not the first time this had happened. I had even done a clean reinstallation of my Mojave OS in my bid to solve this problem.

***I do not wish to update my OS to Catalina just because of this preview issue. I have a number of 32-bit apps that I need for my work.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe consider doing TimeMachine Backups to avoid losing important data and edits. Do you have any Cloud connected? Maybe try exporting the documents and check if the exported ones will also be changed. Btw, what kind of documents are you working on (pdf?)

Comment: I do not have my iCloud connected. I do not think the connection of iCloud with my Macbook should be related to this issue. 
I do edits on simple pdf documents. I am currently in college and most of the study materials are in PDF. 
Are there any solutions to solving the issue where Preview is not showing the latest document format?

Comment: It **shouldn't** have anything to do with iCloud, but saving a document **should** just simply work, too. You could try some basics for weird issues like: changing the save location, trying different document, try a different pdf reader, restart (maybe also in single user mode), SMC reset, if possible try a different computer,... Unfortunately though, I don't have a solution, otherwise I'd post it ;)